# Translation of "ramped window"

Tags: traduction, anglais, informatique, linguistique

In natural language processing, when computing a window based cooccurence matrix, a ramped window will count closer words more.

What is the translation of ramped window in French?

---

A window based cooccurence matrix is computed as follows (when no ramped window is used, simply counting the closest neighborhood words):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Finding information was hard<sup>1</sup> and I had to leave the NLP aspects aside to focus on co-occurrence<sup>2</sup>. That way, I was able to find several questions or documents which make use of "***fenêtre glissante***".

"*Glissant*" here would mean "sliding": the idea is that the window is not something fixed, it moves to accompany your movement while you count the occurrences<sup>3</sup>.

This seems to match what I understand from your description, but I would be more at ease if someone more knowledgeable of co-occurrence than me could confirm these are the same thing.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> I am not sure I fully understand all the concepts, especially how the matrix would be calculated without a ramped window.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> I found French accepts only "[*cooccurrence*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cooccurrence)" while English also accepts "[co-occurrence](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cooccurrence)". I will use the later for readability (it helps distinguishing from "concurrence" for fast readers.</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup> Once more, having been unable to find a definition for the phrase, I extrapolate from common uses of "*fenêtre*" and "*glissant*".</sub>

Comment: Thanks! From my understanding, ramped window is a special kind of sliding window, where items are weighed with respect to their position in the window. I believe "fenêtre glissante" is the correct translation for sliding window, but ramped window is a bit more specific. I though of "fenêtre glissante pondérée", but then again ramped window is a bit more specific (weights dependent on the closeness to the center of the window).